# Is there any Card Game Framework?

Tags: c#, java, card-game

Please let's avoid the discussion of creating/using a game framework or not.

I would like to create a small framework for card games or use one if it exists. Does anyone knows one?

Preferably written in Java or C#.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is a pretty niche video game genre, I doubt that you'll find a framework specifically suited for it. Good luck though!

Comment: Pretty specific stuff for a framework to target. An event driven framework might be a decent fit for this style of game though?

Comment: There are so many card games I didn't thought it would be very specific. @Layoric what are you suggestions for an event driven framework?

Something to reuse code which draw cards, create random decks, manage turns, compare cards would be beneficial for all card games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For C#**

I have used and really helpful the following card game framework

- https://github.com/bhappyman/DeckOfCards

Microsoft has built a nice library/framework for Card Game

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20303

**For Java**

Both of them I used and will be helpful for you

- http://www.ethanwilder.com/node/23
- http://kenai.com/projects/jnag/pages/Home

Answer (score 1):

I've never used them but you can try those:

http://code.google.com/p/wagic/

http://www.ethanwilder.com/node/23

http://gccg.sourceforge.net/

And for the future - Google really IS your friend :)

Answer (score -2):

not a framework, but here's some java code that may be of use:

```
package sample;
import java.util.*;
enum Rank { 
    joker(new Character('*'),"Joker"),aceLow(new Character('a'),"Ace(low)"),deuce(new Character('2'),"Deuce"),trey(new Character('3'),"Trey"),four(new Character('4'),"Four"),five(new Character('5'),"Five"),six(new Character('6'),"Six"),seven(new Character('7'),"Seven"),eight(new Character('8'),"Eight"),nine(new Character('9'),"Nine"),ten(new Character('T'),"Ten"),jack(new Character('J'),"Jack"),queen(new Character('Q'),"Queen"),king(new Character('K'),"King"),aceHigh(new Character('A'),"Ace");
    Rank(final Character c,final String s) {
        this.c=c;
        this.s=s;
    }
    public static Rank fromInt(int n) {
        for(Rank r:Rank.values())
            if(r.ordinal()==n)
                return r;
        return null;
    }
    public static Rank fromCharacter(char c) {
        for(Rank r:Rank.values())
            if(r.c==c)
                return r;
        return null;
    }
    public static Rank[] fromCharacters(final String cards) {
        final Rank[] rank=new Rank[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            rank[i]=Rank.fromCharacter(cards.charAt(i));
        return rank;
    }
    public Character toCharacter() {
        return c;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static String toString(final Rank[] rank) {
        String s="";
        for(Rank r:rank)
            s+=r.toCharacter();
        return s;
    }
    final Character c;
    final String s;
}
enum Suit {
    joker(new Character('*'),"Joker"),clubs(new Character('c'/* try character for a real dimond? */),"Club"),diamonds(new Character('d'),"Diamond"),hearts(new Character('h'),"Heart"),spades(new Character('s'),"Spade");
    Suit(final Character c,final String s) {
        this.c=c;
        this.s=s;
    }
    public static Suit fromCharacter(char c) {
        for(Suit s:Suit.values())
            if(s.c==c)
                return s;
        return null;
    }
    public Character toCharacter() {
        return c;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static String toString(final Suit[] suit) {
        String s_="";
        for(Suit s:suit)
            s_+=s.toCharacter();
        return s_;
    }
    public static boolean areSuited(final Suit[] suit) {
        final int n=suit.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            if(suit[i]!=suit[i+1])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    final Character c;
    final String s;
}
enum Card {
    joker(Rank.joker,Suit.joker),
    aceLowOfClubs(Rank.aceLow,Suit.clubs),
    aceLowOfDiamonds(Rank.aceLow,Suit.diamonds),
    aceLowOfHearts(Rank.aceLow,Suit.hearts),
    aceLowOfSpades(Rank.aceLow,Suit.spades),
    dueceOfClubs(Rank.deuce,Suit.clubs),
    dueceOfDiamonds(Rank.deuce,Suit.diamonds),
    dueceOfHearts(Rank.deuce,Suit.hearts),
    dueceOfSpades(Rank.deuce,Suit.spades),
    treyOfClubs(Rank.trey,Suit.clubs),
    treyOfDiamonds(Rank.trey,Suit.diamonds),
    treyOfHearts(Rank.trey,Suit.hearts),
    treyOfSpades(Rank.trey,Suit.spades),
    fourOfClubs(Rank.four,Suit.clubs),
    fourOfDiamonds(Rank.four,Suit.diamonds),
    fourOfHearts(Rank.four,Suit.hearts),
    fourOfSpades(Rank.four,Suit.spades),
    fiveOfClubs(Rank.five,Suit.clubs),
    fiveOfDiamonds(Rank.five,Suit.diamonds),
    fiveOfHearts(Rank.five,Suit.hearts),
    fiveOfSpades(Rank.five,Suit.spades),
    sixOfClubs(Rank.six,Suit.clubs),
    sixOfDiamonds(Rank.six,Suit.diamonds),
    sixOfHearts(Rank.six,Suit.hearts),
    sixOfSpades(Rank.six,Suit.spades),
    sevenOfClubs(Rank.seven,Suit.clubs),
    sevenOfDiamonds(Rank.seven,Suit.diamonds),
    sevenOfHearts(Rank.seven,Suit.hearts),
    sevenOfSpades(Rank.seven,Suit.spades),
    eightOfClubs(Rank.eight,Suit.clubs),
    eightOfDiamonds(Rank.eight,Suit.diamonds),
    eightOfHearts(Rank.eight,Suit.hearts),
    eightOfSpades(Rank.eight,Suit.spades),
    nineOfClubs(Rank.nine,Suit.clubs),
    nineOfDiamonds(Rank.nine,Suit.diamonds),
    nineOfHearts(Rank.nine,Suit.hearts),
    nineOfSpades(Rank.nine,Suit.spades),
    tenOfClubs(Rank.ten,Suit.clubs),
    tenOfDiamonds(Rank.ten,Suit.diamonds),
    tenOfHearts(Rank.ten,Suit.hearts),
    tenOfSpades(Rank.ten,Suit.spades),
    jackOfClubs(Rank.jack,Suit.clubs),
    jackOfDiamonds(Rank.jack,Suit.diamonds),
    jackOfHearts(Rank.jack,Suit.hearts),
    jackOfSpades(Rank.jack,Suit.spades),
    queenOfClubs(Rank.queen,Suit.clubs),
    queenOfDiamonds(Rank.queen,Suit.diamonds),
    queenOfHearts(Rank.queen,Suit.hearts),
    queenOfSpades(Rank.queen,Suit.spades),
    kingOfClubs(Rank.king,Suit.clubs),
    kingOfDiamonds(Rank.king,Suit.diamonds),
    kingOfHearts(Rank.king,Suit.hearts),
    kingOfSpades(Rank.king,Suit.spades),
    aceOfClubs(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.clubs),
    aceOfDiamonds(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.diamonds),
    aceOfHearts(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.hearts),
    aceOfSpades(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.spades);
    private Card(Rank rank,Suit suit) {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    public Rank rank() {
        return rank;
    }
    public Suit suit() {
        return suit;
    }
    public String toString() {
        if(rank.equals(Rank.joker)||suit.equals(Suit.joker))
            return "Joker";
        else return rank+" of "+suit+'s';
    }
    public static String toString(final Card[] card) {
        String s=new String();
        for(int i=0;i<card.length;i++) {
            if(i>0)
                s+=", ";
            s+=card[i].toCharacters();
        }
        return s;
    }
    public String toCharacters() {
        return ""+rank().toCharacter()+suit().toCharacter();
    }
    public static Card instance(Rank rank,Suit suit) { // some hack for speed
        final int n=4*rank.ordinal()+suit.ordinal();
        //System.out.println(rank+" "+suit+" "+n);
        return element[4*rank.ordinal()+suit.ordinal()];
    }
    static Card[] create(int standards,int jokers) {
        int cards=0;
        Card card[]=new Card[standards*52+jokers];
        for(int i=0;i<standards;i++)
            for(Suit suit:EnumSet.range(Suit.clubs,Suit.spades))
                for(Rank rank:EnumSet.range(Rank.deuce,Rank.aceHigh))
                    card[cards++]=instance(rank,suit);
        for(int i=0;i<jokers;i++)
            card[cards++]=instance(Rank.joker,Suit.joker);
        return card;
    }
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private static final Card element[]={joker,joker,joker,joker,joker,aceLowOfClubs,aceLowOfDiamonds,aceLowOfHearts,aceLowOfSpades,dueceOfClubs,dueceOfDiamonds,dueceOfHearts,dueceOfSpades,treyOfClubs,treyOfDiamonds,treyOfHearts,treyOfSpades,fourOfClubs,fourOfDiamonds,fourOfHearts,fourOfSpades,fiveOfClubs,fiveOfDiamonds,fiveOfHearts,fiveOfSpades,sixOfClubs,sixOfDiamonds,sixOfHearts,sixOfSpades,sevenOfClubs,sevenOfDiamonds,sevenOfHearts,sevenOfSpades,eightOfClubs,eightOfDiamonds,eightOfHearts,eightOfSpades,nineOfClubs,nineOfDiamonds,nineOfHearts,nineOfSpades,tenOfClubs,tenOfDiamonds,tenOfHearts,tenOfSpades,jackOfClubs,jackOfDiamonds,jackOfHearts,jackOfSpades,queenOfClubs,queenOfDiamonds,queenOfHearts,queenOfSpades,kingOfClubs,kingOfDiamonds,kingOfHearts,kingOfSpades,aceOfClubs,
        aceOfDiamonds,aceOfHearts,aceOfSpades};
}
```

Comment: Just posting code is not a good answer. And it's not even commented code.